# Dlib LNK2001 unresolved external symbol USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_2

Tags: c++, linker, dlib

I am trying to implement the DLIB 19.15 library to my app. I generated the dlib project for Windows Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 and made a Release build using CMAKE.
In the project I have added directories and additional dependencies.

But during compilation I have following error

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_2

How Can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://dlib.net/faq.html#WhydoIgetUSERERRORinconsistentbuildconfigurationseedlibfaq2

Comment: [this](https://blog.csdn.net/u012525096/article/details/78276470) help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 9):

Meet the same problem. You need to add one cpp file named `dlib_path\dlib\all\source.cpp` from the dlib source directory to your project and re-compile it. **Do not copy it to your project path**, just add it from dlib source directory.